# Code coverage on single line if statements

Tags: php, phpunit

I am new to PHP and using PHPunit.  With this I am working on a project and trying to keep a 100% code coverage for my unit tests.  I have found PHPunit will make a single line "if" statement as covered even when the unit tests never evaluate TRUE on that line.  Is there a way to get PHPunit code coverage to recognize this?

Example - the following line will show as covered even though the exception never gets thrown:

```
if (false) throw new \Exception('This never gets thrown.');
```

Example - if I write my code like this, the code coverage shows accurate (but I prefer not to write my code like this):

```
if (false) {
  throw new \Exception('This never gets thrown.');
}
```

Is there a way to keep my code as a single line IF statement and have PHPunit show when the right side of the IF statement is never executed?

Comment: You are making two mistakes here:- 1 using single line if statements. 2 insisting on 100% code coverage. The first is bad practice and the second is fool's gold.

Comment: I suspect there is no way to do this. Because the if is on a single line that line *is* executed. Braceless if statements also make me nervous. IMHO they are harder to read and it's unintuitive what this line does: `if(false) echo "Hello ";echo "World!";`.

Answer (score 0):

There are previous talks about this, but it basically comes down to the parsing of the PHP code via the PHP interpreter, and the XDebug and other tools.  Without the braces, these tools do not see the code as distinct lines, therefore they do not get marked as being code covered correctly. Using the braces is the only way to correct the results at this time.